# Put error into quickfix window

Tags: vimrc, autocmd, quickfix

I can customize some error display in my file like highlight all white space at the end of each line by:

```
:match ErrorMsg /\s\+$/
```

Can I put all the error I found into quickfix windows that I can go through it one by one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`:vimgrep /pattern/ %`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/quickfix.html#:vimgrep) to search the current file for `pattern` and put the results in the quickfix list.

There is also [`:grep`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/quickfix.html#:grep) which works in the same way but uses an external program to do the search.

You did not ask for it but in simple situations (like removing trailing spaces) you can also use the [`:substitute`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/change.html#:s) command. For example with

```
:%s/\s\+$//ec
```

you will be walked through every match in the file and can confirm if you want it removed. (`e` is to ignore errors like "no matches found" and `c` is for interactive confirming every replacement)

Comment: this will automatically jump to first error, can it just open quickfix but not jump to it?

Comment: Yes it is in the docs I linked ;) use the `j` flag. You should always read the docs!!

Comment: ah..sorry, use mobile to read and did not notice the link. Thanks again.